# Replacing loop variables requires time (when instantiating a wrapper)

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity

Why can't I instantiate this List wrapper in constant time? The list is already created (and not a generator), and I'm just saving it in my class. Lists are passed by reference, so please explain. I'm really confused, and can't seem to find answers.

**UPDATE**: clearing the loop variables at the beginning of the loop offsets the time to there. But doesn't solve the issue.

**UPDATE 2**: by extending the list I was able to avoid the time loss for clearing and generating the first half of the list again.

- Class:

  ```py
  """
  List instantiate test
  """
  class List:
      """
      List wrapper
      """
      def __init__(self, a: list[Number]):
          self.list = a
  ```
- Main:

  ```py
  from datetime import datetime, timedelta
  Number = int | float
  def main() -> None:
      generate_list: timedelta = timedelta()
      instantiate: timedelta = timedelta()
      size: int = 2 ** 25
      while True:
          start: datetime = datetime.now()
          lst: list[Number] = list(range(size, 0, -1))
          generate_list += datetime.now() - start
          print(f"Total time generating lists:            {generate_list}")
          start: datetime = datetime.now()
          _: List = List(lst)
          instantiate += datetime.now() - start
          print(f"Total time instantiating List wrappers: {instantiate}")
          size *= 2
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  Total time generating lists:            0:00:00.849742
  Total time instantiating List wrappers: 0:00:00.000019
  Total time generating lists:            0:00:02.465526
  Total time instantiating List wrappers: 0:00:00.300718
  Total time generating lists:            0:00:05.719437
  Total time instantiating List wrappers: 0:00:00.985957
  ...
  ```
- Main with clearing:

  ```py
  def main() -> None:
      generate_list: timedelta = timedelta()
      instantiate: timedelta = timedelta()
      clearing: timedelta = timedelta()
      size: int = 2 ** 25
      lst: list[Number] = []
      lst_wrapper: List = None
      while True:
          start: datetime = datetime.now()
          lst.clear()
          lst_wrapper = None
          clearing += datetime.now() - start
          print(f"Total time clearing:                    {clearing}")
          start: datetime = datetime.now()
          lst = list(range(size, 0, -1))
          generate_list += datetime.now() - start
          print(f"Total time generating lists:            {generate_list}")
          start: datetime = datetime.now()
          lst_wrapper = List(lst)
          instantiate += datetime.now() - start
          print(f"Total time instantiating List wrappers: {instantiate}")
          size *= 2
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  Total time clearing:                    0:00:00.000005
  Total time generating lists:            0:00:00.825880
  Total time instantiating List wrappers: 0:00:00.000006
  Total time clearing:                    0:00:00.354571
  Total time generating lists:            0:00:02.449832
  Total time instantiating List wrappers: 0:00:00.000026
  Total time clearing:                    0:00:00.996483
  Total time generating lists:            0:00:05.796596
  Total time instantiating List wrappers: 0:00:00.000046
  ```
- Main with extending:

  ```py
  def main() -> None:
      generate_list: timedelta = timedelta()
      instantiate: timedelta = timedelta()
      start: int = 2 ** 24
      end: int = 2 ** 25
      start_time: datetime = datetime.now()
      lst: list[Number] = list(range(0, -start, -1))
      generate_list += datetime.now() - start_time
      print(f"Total time generating lists:            {generate_list}")
      while True:
          start_time = datetime.now()
          lst.extend(range(-start, -end, -1))
          generate_list += datetime.now() - start_time
          print(f"Total time generating lists:            {generate_list}")
          start_time = datetime.now()
          _: List = List(lst)
          instantiate += datetime.now() - start_time
          print(f"Total time instantiating List wrappers: {instantiate}")
          start *= 2
          end *= 2
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  Total time generating lists:            0:00:00.514641
  Total time generating lists:            0:00:00.981933
  Total time instantiating List wrappers: 0:00:00.000005
  Total time generating lists:            0:00:01.851684
  Total time instantiating List wrappers: 0:00:00.000025
  Total time generating lists:            0:00:03.668982
  Total time instantiating List wrappers: 0:00:00.000030
  ```

Comment: What time are you m4easuring?

Comment: The time it takes to instantiate the class, after creating the array.

Comment: Aren't you looking at the implementation with clearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not just measuring the time it takes to instantiate the `List` wrapper class. You're also measuring the time it takes to *throw away* the old instance.

When you assign a new `List` instance to `_`, that removes the last reference to the old instance. The old instance had the last reference to the old list, so the old instance and its list both become reclaimable. Python's reference-counting system detects this and frees them. Most of the ints also get reclaimed at this point, though a few stick around due to small int caching.

The first time through the loop, there's no old instance, so none of this happens. On subsequent iterations, the cost of this cleanup accounts for the extra runtime.

Comment: Is there any way to clear them faster maybe? Or should I just extend my list?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find a solution by simply extending the list. (It also generates the new list quicker) = win-win